# php to display file information and download link if files are present - How to adjust for multiple files

Tags: php, file, list, directory

I have a piece of php that if a specified folder has a file in, it will display the filename, date created and present a download button, if the folder is empty it will show nothing. This works very well but if I have more than one file in the folder it bunches all the filenames together - what I want is the separate information displayed for every file.

To help you understand the problem here is an image showing the problem and the code. I got very far on my own but its way above my head, I just cant see a simple way to correct the problem. The code may look very awkward and odd as I'm totally new at this but it looks visually right on the browser. I would really appreciate any help thank you.

Here is an image of the problem: http://i46.tinypic.com/m79cvs.png

```
    <?php if (!empty($thelist)) { ?>
<p class="style12"><u>Fix</u></p>
<p class="style12"><?=$thelist?><?php echo " - " ?> <?php $filename = '../../customers/client1/client1.fix.exe';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "" . date ("m/d/Y", filemtime($filename));
}
?> <?php echo " - <a href='download.php?f=client1/client1.fix.exe'><b>Download</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a     href='download.php?f=client1/client1.fix.exe'>
<img src='../css/images/dlico.png' alt='download' width='35' height='32'     align='absmiddle' /></a>" ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list (`$thelist`) contains your files, yes?
You are not working on the `$thelist`, but on the `$filename` which is a hardcoded string.
Why? Currently you are outputting `<?=$thelist?>` and it looks like concatenated string from filenames. I would suggest that `$thelist` should be something like an array of your files. Then you could iterate over the files and output html dynamically for each entry.

```
<?php
    // define your directory here
    $directory = xy; 

    // fetches all executable files in that directory and loop over each
    foreach(glob($directory.'/*.exe') as $file) { 
        // output each name and mtime
        echo $file . '-' . date ("m/d/Y", filemtime($file));
        // or you might also build links dynamically
        // $directory needs to be added here
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.' - Size: '.filesize($file).'</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm too inexperienced to know exactly what everything means so I'm not surprised if I did some things wrong, but thank you I will try to modify your example so that it works correctly to display the directory listing with the download button etc.  thank you.

Comment: I understand. Ok, i hope my example is useful. If so, please accept it as answer.

Comment: It looks promising, though I've just begun integrating it and there was an error on that last line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'    echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.' - Size: '.filesize($file).'</a>';

Comment: i missed the semicolon on the line before. i will edit the answer.

Comment: I've got it half way there but I noticed now when I started formatting the text like adding <p class="style12"></p> etc it displays each part on its own line, I have no idea why it is doing this? And it does this with whatever style I give it. If I take it out it goes back to displaying all the parts on one line like it is supposed to.

Comment: It's the <p> (paragraph). It will automatically insert a line break. Try using <span> or <div> with a style to format your text.

Comment: Im struggling to get the php working though that only displays the information if there is a file present. The closest I got was to display the "Fix:" text but for every file instead of just displaying it one time as it should be. - If I add the relevant code in the way it used to be the 'Fix' text either stays there permanently or never appears, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You might post your php code on http://codepad.org/ and then post the link to your code here. So i can take a look where the problem is.

Comment: hi. I have included the code how it is now, working - its when I try to reintroduce the code which makes it only appear if there are files in the folder when it goes wrong. http://codepad.org/qS9C0Twn I have tried various methods but I'm maybe just programming it wrong. The original code "<?php if (!empty($thelist)) { ?>
" etc just doesnt seem to work.

Comment: (I did of course replace $thelist with $directory etc to set it up, but that may also have been wrong.)

Comment: Please give this a try: http://codepad.org/f8CZRfRP I have added comments, for better understanding whats going on.

Comment: Please comment the line containing var_dump($files). Then the debug output is gone. Line 22! You got it i guess :)